# Remove Cell color when cell color is created with a Macro Code

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I created a Macro to change a cell to yellow when a change is made (top Macro). I now want to create a code so I can create a button to click to remove all of the yellow that was created with the top Macro.

I was able to find the bottom code which does turn manually highlighted cells from yellow back to white but not cells turned yellow from my Top Macro.

Below are the formats I used:

***To create the Yellow Color when a change is made:***

```
'Highlight cells yellow if change occurs

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

***To Remove Yellow Highlight (only works for Manual change- not the Macro)***

```
Sub RemoveYellowFillColor()
Dim cell As Range

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Ensure Cell Range Is Selected
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
MsgBox ("A2:Z1000")
Exit Sub
End If

'Loop Through Each Cell
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
  cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your top macro should probably be `Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow`. `Interior.Color` and `Interior.ColorIndex` aren't the same.

Comment: I think BigBen is right, I'm on my phone so can't test, but vbYellow and ColorIndex 6 are probably different colours (albeit not perceptible to the human eye) so the IF statement is never true.

Comment: Okay, so I did that and it does delete the color, but only if the cursor is in that cell. Do you know what I need to add to make it choose a range of cells? I thought I had that code in this part 'Ensure Cell Range Is Selected
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox ("A2:Z1000")
    Exit Sub
    End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Rev. 1 of my answer:

As noted in comments, change from `Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6` to `Target.Interior.ColorIndex = vbYellow` in `Workbook_SheetChange`.

Then update your macro as follows:

```
Sub RemoveYellowFillColor()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop Through Each Cell
For Each ws In Worksheets
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
Next cell
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After running this macro, `vbYellow` fill will be removed from all cells on all worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!! You are awesome!